# Laravel Session is not persistent in staging enviornment

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5, traefik

I have created a simple laravel app. Session is persistent in local but in my staging enviornment it is not persistent. I am using nginx in local and traefik in staging.

Comment: which session driver are you using? If it is "file", make sure "storage/framework/sessions" folder has writing permissions. If it is "array", it won't be persistent. Check which driver you are using in "config/sessions.php"

Comment: I am using database

Comment: Do you have sessions table on your database? If so, try running "php artisan cache:clear && php artisan key:generate". Then check what is your "cookie" value in config/sessions.php and check if database entry is being created on sessions table and if such cookie is getting created in your browser.

Comment: I am not getting unique session for all user. I am able to access to someones others account when someone logged in after my login. This type of problem i am facing. But it works perfectly in local

Comment: session entry is created in database.

Comment: check if cookie is being created in the browser

Comment: Yes it is created